# If $V\subseteq W$ are algebraic sets, then each irreducible component of $V$ is contained in some irreducible component of $W$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to find a proof for problem 1.27 in the Algebraic Curves by Fulton. I thought I had answered it but I found a mistake and now I am struggling to find a way to prove it.

The claim goes as follows

> Let $V,W$ be algebraic sets in $\mathbb{A}^n(k)$ with $V\subseteq W$. Then each irreducible component of V is contained in some irreducible componet of $W$.

I have tried examples to see if this is true but nothing seem to click. Here are some of the arguments I've tried:

- Let $W_i$ be the irreducible components of $W$. Clearly $V=\bigcup_{i}(V\cap W_i)$ and $V\cap W_i$ contained in $W_i$. By Theorem 2 (in particular uniqueness), if $V\cap W_i$ is irreducible for each $i$, then the result follows. It suffices to show that $I(V\cap W_i)$ is prime by Proposition 1, which I can't do. I've tried showing that $k[X_1,...,X_n]/I(V\cap W_i)$ is an integral domain but that didn't get to far either.
- Let $V_1$ be an irreducible component of $W$, and $W=\bigcup_{i=1}^mW_i$. Suppose $V_1$ is not contained in any $W_i$. Then as $V\subseteq W$, $V_1\subseteq \bigcup_{j\in J}W_j$ for some indexing set $J\subseteq\{1,...,m\}$. If $J=\{1,...,m\}$, then $V_1=W$, but $W$ is reducible and $V_1$ is irreducible, so $J\subset\{1,...,m\}$. If $J=\{1,...,m-1\}$ after relabelling, then $V_0=W\backslash W_m$, but $V_0$ is irreducible and $W\backslash W_m$ is reducible, so $J\subset\{1,...,m-1\}$. This repeats until $J=\{1\}$ in which case $V_0=W\backslash\bigcup_{i=2}^mW_i=W_1$. But this is contradiction to $V_1$ not being contained in any $W_i$.

I started typing the last one out but then an idea hit me and I continued typing. I believe it is correct, if not I'm back to square one.

EDIT: I checked my proof, it's not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every irreducible subset  $I\subset W$ of $W$ is contained in an irreducible component $W_i$ of $W$:  $I\subset W_i$. Apply this to any irreducible subset $I=V_j\subset V$ of $V$.

Comment: Sorry, I realised that and how silly my comment was! Thanks for the response.

Comment: I can see that this works. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome, dear Purple.